# Expunge a corrupted Excel program

Tags: ms-office, macos

All my downloaded spreadsheets are going to Excel which is totally corrupted. I want them to open in Numbers instead and ditch Excel if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Just move it to trash from the Applications folder. [This page](http://www.officeformachelp.com/office/install/installed-files-list-for-office-2011/) has list of files installed by Office 2011, but you don't have to care about them if you just want to remove Excel.

You can also change the default applications for file types from Finder's information windows (⌘I).

[image]